# How to calculate this Ei(x)-involved definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I want to solve the integral attached below by means of residue theorem. I tried the common integration ways and seeked references(e.g, Rjadov, et. al).

Finally, I decided to solve this integral by means of  " Residue Theorem ". Can anyone help me ?

$$
\int_u^\infty \frac{Ei(-x)e^{-px}}{(x-\beta)}dx\,.
$$

$$
p>0\ ,\ \beta>0\ \ ,\ u>0 \ , \  \  u < \beta
$$

Comment: We must have $u>\beta$, otherwise we are integrating through a singularity.

Comment: i want to solve the both cases, $u > \beta$  &&  $u<\beta$.

right now, i want to solve the case u<\beta by means of residue theorem

Comment: if $u<\beta$ the integrand function is not integrable in the usual way, so you have to say you want to compute the principal value of the integral.

Comment: i want to know:

what is the best closed-curve for using cauchy integral theorem. And information about singular points of exponential integral

Comment: The question is still missing informations about what you have attempted.  $0$ and $\infty$ are branch points for the exponential integral; given that, it is not trivial that the integral can be actually computed through the residue theorem, the Laplace transform looks best suited. What would have you tried if the problem was to compute 
$$ \int_{u}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)e^{-px}}{x-\beta}\,dx $$ ?

Comment: i think laplace transform must be from $0$ to $\infty$

(i am not good with latex (M.S office user) and i have registered here today )

Comment: the answer is $2\pi$ Res$(x=\beta)$.  i think

Comment: So $u$ has no role. Strange, don't you think?

Comment: I know methods of integration. I am just saying that your question is not well-posed and lacks any attempts from your side.

Comment: By $u$ I meant the left endpoint of the integration range of $\int_{u}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)e^{-px}}{x-\beta}\,dx$. You said that this integral is just given by the residue of the integrand function in $x=\beta$, but that is clearly wrong, since in such a case the value of the integral is the same for any choice of the parameter $u$.

Comment: So, just to simplify things: you may compute $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx $$ through the residue theorem, but the trick does not work anymore for computing $$\int_{17}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx,$$ for instance. Same issue in the problem you posed.

Comment: :D , i know. the integration region must includ the point x = $\beta$

i just didnt have time to draw the curves , do the limits and solve the problem. the 2$pi$i Res(x=...) is a way does no related to this. its a joke !

Comment: Ok, i have modified the question.