# How to solve this definite Integral containing $E_{1}${.}!

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

The integral is:
$$\int_{N}^{\infty}\frac{E_{1}(cz+d)}{az+b}e^{-pz}dz$$

where, $E_{1}${.} is the exponential integral, and

$$a>0,\ b>0,\ c>0,\ d>0,\ p>0,\ N>0.$$

This is similar to [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359247/how-to-calculate-this-eix-involved-definite-integral) which I don't have any Idea to solve it.

Any hint or coment  would be appreciated. It must be noted that I already have solved the integral using approximation of exponential integral. I am seeking an exact solution possible.

Regards.

Comment: If $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}=0$ and $c=p$, then a simple substitution or integration by parts is enough to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Does $z$ depend on $x$ somehow?

Comment: @A.G it was a typo, thanks for correction

Comment: @Lucian would you give me the reference? I am working on the expressions you written.

Comment: @Lucian the $c=p$ does not  hold unfortunately